# Have a go web service that receives a post, but unclear how to send response back to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, go

Morning,

I have some go code that receives a json post and does some stuff, but I want to send back to jquery the result or a message.

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)
type Deploy struct {
    Environmentid string `json:"environmentid"`
    Versionid string `json:"versionid"`
    Dtp string `json:"dtp"`
}
func deploy(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    if origin := req.Header.Get("Origin"); origin != "" {
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS,     PUT, DELETE")
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-    Token, Authorization")
    }
    // Stop here if its Preflighted OPTIONS request
    if req.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }
    if req.Method == "POST" {
        d := Deploy{}
        err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&d)
        if err != nil {
            panic("Can't decode Json received in post")
        }
        fmt.Println("Deploy: " + d.Environmentid + "," + d.Versionid + "," +   d.Dtp)
        // Run command
        cmd := exec.Command("/bin/myscript.sh", strings.Split(fmt.Sprintf("-e %s -v %s", d.Environmentid, d.Versionid), " ")...)
        cmdOut, cmdErr := cmd.Output()
        if cmdErr != nil {
                panic(cmdErr)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(cmdOut))
    }
```

The jquery I have right now:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: url,
     cache:false,
     crossDomain: true,
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     data: jsonData,
               dataType: 'json',
     success:function(result) {
           $('#target').html('Request was sent successfully...');
           console.log(result);
      },
      error:function(xhr,status,error) {
           //alert(error);
      }
 });
```

I see the 3 things I send just fine.
I think I saw some reference to some option called callback for the $.ajax.  I am guessing that that allows me to put a function name to receive a response.  An example of how to receive a json response that has the success or error from the go server would be appreciated, and how to send the response from the go server to this callback.

Comment: This IS your callback: `success:function(result) {
           $('#target').html('Request was sent successfully...');
           console.log(result);
      }` - the result should be your JSON but I do not see the server return JSON

Comment: I am not sure what your output looks like from `myscript.sh`, but as a starter you can try sending that back.  Instead of printing to stdout with `fmt.Println(string(cmdOut))`, try `fmt.Fprint(rw, string(cmdOut))`

Comment: Is this a streamed response?  In that, when my script runs, can it say "Starting to run..." and have that go to the web page and then have it say the last message when it is done, which is a bunch of stuff (i.e., not just a message saying Done).

Comment: Like Mark suggests below, look into websockets.

Comment: For some reason it throws error: error and I see the go server does not show it received the post json data.  If I run it again, it does not throw error, but when the go server gets to the end and writes the ftm.Fprint(rw, string(cmdOUt)), I do not see anything displaying on the web page that I would have thought would go to web page and the console.log.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ajax` call you've already specified a callback to receive a response; that's what `success` is, and it will receive the data provided by the server's `http.ResponseWriter`.

If what you mean is that after the http request/response cycle is complete, at some later time you want the server to initiate a message to the client, then you need to be looking at websockets.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
func ajaxResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, res map[string]string) {
  // set the proper headerfor application/json
  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")             
  // encode your response into json and write it to w
  err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(res)                          
  if err != nil {                                                
    log.Println(err)                                             
  }                                                              
}
```

And call it like this:

```
func apiFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  // do stuff
  ajaxResponse(w, map[string]string{"data": "your data here"})
}
```

Edit:

on the client I use "pure" ajax without jquery:

```
// a function to send user info to add them to a database           
function addUser() {                                                
  // new request                                                    
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                                   
  // type (eg POST, GET, etc), and api endpoint                     
  xhr.open('POST', '/api/addUser');                                    
  // tell it you're sending json                                    
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');         
  // call this function on load                                     
  xhr.onload = function() {                                         
    // if it was successful                                         
    if (xhr.status === 200) {                                       
      // parse the response into json                               
      var userInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);                  
      // use the json to change your apps UI                        
      document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = userInfo.error; 
    }                                                               
  };                                                                
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({                                         
    // user info here                                               
    error: "nil"                                                    
  }));                                                              
}
```

Comment: Okay, I need to resolve something first.  Why does this code go immediately to : {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}, but I see the json post stuff arrive at go server?  "environmentid":"95158277","versionid":"94470491","dtp":"2017/02/02 09:11"} .

Comment: Running with curl seems to show it working:     2017/01/31 09:30:48 curl/7.29.0
Deploy: 95158277,94470491,stuff                  <---shows it got post
{ "deploymentState": "SUCCESS" }                <---message at end with ajaxResponse.  But web page is not working.  It throws that statusText error.  I thought I had cross-domain working as I see the post arrive and can print values to screen and use them in the go server, but I guess web page is failing immediately so I can't send message back to it.

Comment: I don't know if I really understand. I use pure ajax (without jquery), I will edit my answer to show an example of client side ajax request and maybe that can help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my go server code and added a .ajaxSetup option in the client web page to disable cache and async.  The javascript url changed to fit into how they example was using post with a param so that it could store the array of post information.  This would allow me to add a GET to retrieve information on a specific request if I desired.

My last challenge, and maybe you can help, is that when the response arrives back at the web page it flashes on the screen for a second and then resets the page.  How do I get the result to stay on the screen and retain in the list boxes the response?  It has been a while since I made a page...

Note: My concern is that I had to use the deprecated async cache stuff because the ajax was intermittent at best (i.e., it would not wait for result or even get json to go server if I tried sending a few times without the async and cache options.

```
            $.ajaxSetup({async: false, cache: false});
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    crossOrigin: true,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: jsonData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
                            document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = "<p>" + JSON.stringify(data) + "</p>";
                            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
            });
```

The go server code changed to use gorilla:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

// Deploy Struct
type Deploy struct {
    Environment  string `json:"environmentid"`
    Release      string `json:"versionid"`
    DTP          string `json:"dtp"`
}

var deploys = map[string]*Deploy{}

func main() {
    corsObj:=handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
    methods := []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"}
    headers := []string{"Content-Type"}
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/deploy/{deployKey}", handleDeploy).Methods("POST")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000",   handlers.CORS(handlers.AllowedMethods(methods), handlers.AllowedHeaders(headers), corsObj)(router)))
}

func handleDeploy(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    vars := mux.Vars(req)
    deployKey := vars["deployKey"]

    switch req.Method {
    case "POST":
            deploy := new(Deploy)
            decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
            error := decoder.Decode(&deploy)
            if error != nil {
                    log.Println(error.Error())
                    http.Error(res, error.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                    return
            }
            deploys[deployKey] = deploy

            /*
            outgoingJSON, err := json.Marshal(deploy)
            if err != nil {
                    log.Println(error.Error())
                    http.Error(res, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                    return
            }
            */

            fmt.Println("Deploy: " + deploy.Environment + "," + deploy.Release + "," + deploy.DTP)
            cmd := exec.Command("/u/boop/bin/boop/bam.sh", strings.Split(fmt.Sprintf("-e %s -r %s", deploy.Environment, deploy.Release), " ")...)
            cmdOut, cmdErr := cmd.Output()
            if cmdErr != nil {
                    log.Println(error.Error())
                    http.Error(res, cmdErr.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                    return
            }
            //fmt.Println(string(cmdOut))
            //var s = string(cmdOut)
            //strings.Replace(s,"\n","",-1)

            res.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
            //fmt.Fprint(res, string(outgoingJSON))
            fmt.Fprint(res, string(cmdOut))
    }
```

Comment: Never mind.  I just replaced the type=submit to type=button.  Cheers and thanks for looking at my question.